# How to fix if else statement to determine whether "ok" or "Cancel" is clicked?

Tags: java

This is the code, which helps to display confirm dialog box on screen, First if statement just checks which radio button are pressed, than a confirm dialog box appears, On which there is option available , which is "ok" and "cancel". So when I click either "ok" or "Cancel"  another confirm dialog box appears, which must have to show message, which shows which one is clicked, **but there is an error**, even if I click "ok" , it shows **you pressed cancel**

```
if (Choose == okCancel.getText() && IconChoose == NoneRadioButton.getText())
{
    int response = 
        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, txt, " Message Dialog Box", 
                                      JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
}
else if (response == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION)
{
    JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "You Pressed OK ","", 
                                  JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION);
}

if (response == JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION)
{
    JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "You Pressed CANCEL ","",
                                  JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION);
}
```

Comment: i got the answer... it is just a little error

Comment: "*please read the discription first* [sic]" Please check Google first! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use

```
 .equals() or equalsIgnoreCase();
```

instaed of ==